# DDD: Alternative view of the Model?

Tags: architecture, object-oriented-design, domain-driven-design, aspect-oriented

I have a model class, let's say it's a `Book`. I need it to be displayed on the screen. I want to have an *escaped* version of it, so I do not need to escape fields manually.

What should I do? I can

- add a *wrapper* over the `Book` that returns escaped values (e.g. `EscapedBook`); but every time when I change the book, i need to change the wrapper - at least to add/remove methods.
- run the model through some AOP and generate *proxy* before it is going to be displayed on the screen.
- or run the model through some util that is going to escape all string properties.

IMHO this is not quite a business behavior, so I would like to keep this on the UI layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A wrapper is the right way to go here -- you really want the UI part of the UI layer to just reflect what is given and not be responsible for more than very technical bits of filtering content. I would run with the first option you are looking at and create a specific subclass for the UI layer to handle this task.

The real cost from a writing code perspective isn't having to update your `EscapedBook` whenever the underlying class changes -- underlying classes changing is going to change a lot of things down the logical line. You'd be better off having the internal representation talking to a single class rather than speaking directly to a dozen different things in the front end application.

This front-end specific class could very well be generated via a proxy or AOP process -- that is really a tactical decision depending on what the stack is and what other dependencies you have. You might mean having a straight-through dedicated proxy rather than a separate class. This isn't a horrible idea on the surface but I would prefer the dedciated class concept in the end -- it is more flexible to separate the problems in the end.

The utility class is best avoided here -- you will end up with things like `ContentUtil.CleanPage(book.Pages[1])` all over the UI layer and that will hurt to fix when you re-think things. Globals are bad, even when globals are stateless utility functions.

One thing I would not throw out is having this be generated in the business layer -- generating properly escaped content is a testable business requirement of the application I'd rather test against the business layer versus trying to write automated tests of the UI.

Comment: Hey, @Wyatt Barnett about: "_having this be generated in the business layer_". Do you mean code generation, e.g. to generate wrappers code from current models? (just to clarify)

Comment: Generated in the non pejorative "created/associated by/with" sense. No implication about generated code.

Comment: If `Book` has few (a list of) `Author`s, how would you convert from 'unescaped' to 'escaped' model? You would need to not only to wrap a book, but all it's authors. Basically, every aggregate that is going to be displayed would have its own 'wrapped' version, right?

Comment: Perhaps -- really depends on the objects. I'd expect a major player like authors would need some love. But maybe something simpler like prices would not.